# Injecting model and return value 'with' relationship in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to build application on `Laravel` and I want to know whether we can use `with` relation while injecting the model inside a controller function for example:

I've a model named `Stream` and I've a model named `Standard`. `Standard` belongs to `Stream` so my code looks like:

```
class Standard extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Models\Stream', 'stream_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Now in my `StandardController` I've following function to show the Model:

```
public function show(Standard $standard)
{
    return response()->json(['data' => $standard], 200);
}
```

I'm trying to use `return response()->json(['data' => $standard->with('stream')], 200);` but it is not working accordingly. Can someone suggest me how to execute in this kind of scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `$standard->load('stream')` i.e lazy loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`with()` is for when you're initially getting the model(s). If you already have the model(s) you can instead use `load()`. This is called [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

```
public function show(Standard $standard)
{
    $standard->load('stream');

    return response()->json(['data' => $standard], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1) You can utilize [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources). This is my preferred approach.

2) If API Resources aren't your cup of tea, you just need to load the relationship somehow. One way to do this is `$standard->load('stream')`. Another way is to just access the relation: `$standard->stream`.

What's going on here is that any accessed relations make it into a model's `relations` key, which makes the default json serialization a bit unpredictable. Due to this, I prefer to be explicit with the API resources.

3) You can modify the `Standard` model's `$with` array to include `stream`, but I'm not a fan of this approach as that means every time `Standard` records are fetched, they'll automatically fetch the `stream` relation.

`with()` is a method you call on an Eloquent Builder object that will fetch relations for [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). In this case you are working with a `Model` instance, not an Eloquent Builder.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code. more detailed explanation available at [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

```
$standard->load('stream');
return response()->json(['data' => $standard], 200);
```